Meyer Lemon tree leaves yellowing / no new leaves growing
I purchased a Meyer lemon tree sapling and planted it on May 13th. Last month, I observed that the leaves were turning yellow and no new leaves were appearing. Initially, I assumed this was a typical response to transplanting, but my concern has grown as at least 15 yellowed leaves have fallen off and not been replaced.
I have tried :

Adding Liquid Fertilizer + Slow Release Organic Fertilizer
Moving the tree to an area with Sun All day

Additionnal data :

Temperature since transplanting was around 20°C (68°F) - 30°C (86°F)
I used a soil mix specialized for citrus tree for planting
The plant is in a 65L (17 Gallon) fabric grow-bag
I water every 3rd Day and Fertilize every 23rd day
The plant is on a south facing balcony on the 2nd floor

Would someone be able to help identify what issue is based upon the images ?
Thank you !


